# Case insensitive for the search at the lightning:dualListBox

Tags: lightning, lightning-duallistbox

I have a searchBox for a lightning:dualListBox and written to search according to the searchTerm like below,

```
({
handleInit : function(cmp, event) {
    cmp.set('v.options', cmp.get('v.dataImportFields'));
    this.search(cmp, event);
},

search: function(cmp, event) {
    var searchTerm = cmp.get("v.searchTerm");
    var selectedImport = cmp.get('v.selectedDataImportFields');
    var dataImportFields = cmp.get("v.dataImportFields")
                          .filter(
                              item => !searchTerm ||
                              item.value.match(searchTerm) ||
                              item.label.match(searchTerm));

    for(var key of selectedImport) {
        var item = {
            "value":  key,
            "label": key
        };
        dataImportFields.push(item);
    }
    cmp.set('v.options', dataImportFields);
}
})
```

In the above search it's case sensitive. Is anyone know how to include case insensitive option for the above implementation. I couldn't figure it an easy way to do it.

Comment: why dont you just convert everything to lowercaps?

Comment: What do you mean by everything? I can't convert the dataImportFields value to the lowercase(Because it shows the label name of fields). I can change the searchTerm to lower or upper caps but it only search for some particular use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a case-insensitive regex, you should be able to get the items you're looking for:

```
var searchTerm = new RegExp(cmp.get("v.searchTerm"),"i"); // "i" for insensitive match
```